# What are some good places to get equipment reviews online?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, accessories, reviews

When making gear purchases, it seems sensible to get as much information as possible.

Where are good (i.e. reliably accurate and informative) places to look online for equipment reviews and discussions?

---

Answers here should focus on reviews and comparisons covering equipment *other* than camera bodies and lenses, because those are already covered under these questions:

- [Where can I find reviews of lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-lenses)
- [Where can I find reviews of and tools for comparing cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-and-tools-for-comparing-cameras)

---

This is a "community wiki" post, where answers do not have individual ownership. Please post one suggestion per answer, and use the answers to rate and comment on each site.

Comment: What kind of gear? Tripods, memory cards, flashes, cases, backpacks? The best resources many times specialize in only one area.

Comment: that might be a good idea for a community wiki, a nice overview of good resources for each specific area.

Comment: Yeah, this is what CW is good for. I also think we should focus this specifically on _non-camera_, _non-lens_ gear reviews, since we already have  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/ and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/

Comment: Happy to make it community wiki.  Is there a way I can do that, or does it need a moderator (in which case, please do it)?

Comment: "You friendly neighborhood moderator has cordially converted this question to Community Wiki. If you need any further assistance, please contact the moderators via the `flag` tool, and issue your requests." BEEEP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[B&H Photo Video](http://www.bhphotovideo.com) is not only a great source to buy equipment, but it is a great source of reviews and relevant information about the equipment. I usually just find the category I want, and **sort by the "Top Rated" or "Relevance"** and typically that will direct you right to the most popular model.

[image]

[Amazon](http://www.amazon.com) also has many reviews and has a great system for showing you the **most popular and highest reviewed models in each category**. Overall I've found the reviews on Amazon to become somewhat dated. If a product has been available for a few years, many times the most popular reviews are from day 1. So they may be lacking up to date comparisons. But if you are aware of this, and look beyond the top rated reviews, many times you will find relevant information.

[image]

Personally I enjoy **landscape and nature photography**, so I like to browse the equipment section of the most recent [Outdoor Photography magazine](http://www.outdoorphotographer.com/gear/) that I receive. I've found that if you are really aware of the market, some of the "new equipment" actually has been out for quite a while and the magazine editors just finally picked up on it. But if you aren't worried about being on the cutting edge(which isn't necessary) then this might turn you on to some new gift ideas or things you didn't even realize you *needed*.

Comment: Since this is now community wiki, I suggest breaking these into separate answers. (Maybe the two big online vendors are still logically one answer, but the magazine is probably its own thing.)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, [DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com/) is top-notch for camera body reviews, and right up there for lenses, too.  Really thorough and objective, and they've got some great tools for comparing results of different reviews.

[DxOMark](http://www.dxomark.com/index.php) is a good source of objective data, but I tend to treat them as supporting material rather than primary material.

Answer (score 3):

## Camera bags

- [CamBags](http://www.cambags.com/index.php) : User provided reviews, nice thing is that they allow easy selection of candidate bags (brand/size/camera).

Comment: Geek heaven! ... Must ... not ... buy ... more ... bags...

Answer (score 2):

## Filters

- [LensTip](http://www.lenstip.com/): although they focus on lenses, their filter tests are quite extensive.

  - [UV Filters](http://www.lenstip.com/113.1-article-UV_filters_test.html) + [supplement](http://www.lenstip.com/120.1-article-UV_filters_test_-_supplement.html)
  - [Polarizers](http://www.lenstip.com/115.1-article-Polarizing_filters_test.html) + [supplement](http://www.lenstip.com/119.1-article-Polarizing_filters_test_-_supplement.html)

Answer (score 0):

DPreview was already mentioned; very in-depth and technical.  I think it's important not to rely on 1 review. I also like The Digital Picture (Canon and Nikon) http://www.the-digital-picture.com. It's a lot simpler then DPreview and more compact. (Nice images of equipment) After reading sever professional reviews it is equally as important for me personally to get personal experiences from users that have purchased the equipment on Amazon for example (also already mentioned) or vendor customer review.

Answer (score 0):

[Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com) has excellent reviews of digital cameras with a unique focus on usability and photography applications. *I write those reviews myself, so I'd say its reliable and completely accurate :)*

You can obtain a usability perspective too, mostly for high-end gear, at [Luminous-Landscape](http://www.luminous-landscape.com).

The best place for lens reviews is [SLR Gear](http://www.slrgear.com) - *I don't write single lens reviews because they do it so well.*

For cameras, I think [DC Resource](http://www.dcresource.com) has got very well-balanced reviews that cover most important aspects without being too lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

For lenses for DSLRs, I like to reference http://photozone.de/ for their consistent, clear tests.  There's not a lot of bloat in the language (minimal marketing speak) and the tests are repeatable and comparable among brand lines.

I second the LensTip site, it's how I decided to only go with high quality UV filters on my oldest lenses that are subject to purple fringe.  The rest of the lot were banished to the dusty corners of storage.

Comment: +1 nice site.  Trust the Germans to do this nicely.  Sehr gut!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reviews and tests at [pixel-peeper](http://www.pixel-peeper.com/).