# How can I find a compact camera with an ultra-wide lens?

Tags: focal-length, web, wide-angle, camera-recommendation, ultra-wide

I'm looking to buy a compact camera, and having a very wide angle is important to me. I know that review sites often list the real focal length of the lens, but what I'm looking for is something that will show me current models with actually wide field of view. Is there such a resource?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find reviews of and tools for comparing cameras?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-and-tools-for-comparing-cameras)

Comment: If all else fails, use Google with searchwords "_review compact camera ultra-wide lens_" and select "last year" in Google search tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several web sites which collect information on camera models and provide convenient ways to narrow down to specific options that fit what you need. My favorite is part of the the [Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com/) site. You can use the [Camera Search](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) to narrow down the field by camera type and by focal length in 35mm equivalent terms.

"35mm equivalent" is a little confusing, but, simply, cameras have many different sensor sizes, and by normalizing all of the information to a standard, we can compare between different camera systems and know we're talking about the same field of view. (And, 35mm film camera frame size happens to be the industry standard)

So, the following search will show all current compact cameras with a widest focal length of at least 24mm-e, which is widely (um, pun intended; sorry) regarded as the cut-off where "[ultra-wide](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/10031/1943)" begins:

> http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=compact&focalwide=24

We can also try just a teensy bit wider, limiting to *23mm* or wider, which as of mid-2013 gives no results:

> http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=compact&focalwide=23

Or, we can switch from compact to ultra-compact:

> http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=ultracompact&focalwide=24

which Neocamera defines as cameras up to 28mm at the thickest point. (Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to get the two searches in a combined report, but that's probably okay because there's too many to wade through in one look anyway.)

You could also do a [similar search on DP Review](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams%2CSpecsZoomWide%2CAnnouncementYear&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=Compact%2CUltraCompact%2CSLRLike%2CLargeSensorCompact&paramSpecsZoomWide=24-&paramAnnouncementYearMin=2012), and while their interface is a little more modern and slick, I actually find it more unwieldy. (Checkboxes on the top of the page make sliders appear or disappear down below, and then you set those sliders to change the cameras which appear on a list below that, and then in that list you have to dig further to get to camera details. On the other hand, you *can* include multiple camera types at once, and it's easier if you want, for example, to know what cameras were released between 1994 and 1998.)

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not associated with Neocamera, but @Itai, a Photo-Se regular, is.

Comment: wow neocamera is awesome, thanks for introducing me to it :)

Comment: Why? I do appreciate the site but this reads like a paid advertisement.

Comment: It is not a paid advertisement. I don't know of any better resource, and  I did link to the primary competition and explain why I like this one better. The other alternative would be Snapsort, but their search interface doesn't lend itself to this particular question _and_ I'm very skeptical of their automated recommendations and often-misleading automatic advice.

Comment: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/should-this-question-be-left-open